# Minimize function that takes n vectors as input

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector

I'd like to minimize a function in MATLAB that takes `n` vectors as input

More precisely: I have `n` points in 3D-space that describe a closed curve, let's say the circle.

```
n = 10;
t = linspace(0,1,10);

x = cos(2*pi*t);
y = sin(2*pi*t);
z = zeros(1,length(2*pi*t));

vec = [x;y;z]
scalar = function my_fun(vec)
```

So the points representing the curve in space are defined by `vec(:,1),...,vec(:,n)`. My function takes the points (`vec`) and calculates some kind of energy, so the output is a scalar.

My problem is that I don't know how to set the the variable input such that I can use `fminsearch`. The idea is, if possible, that `fminsearch` vary the points in space to find the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fminsearch` can optimize a function that takes any one array as input. Your function takes one input argument, `vec`, which is a 2D array. This can be directly optimized:

```matlab
init = randn(3,n);
answer = fminsearch(my_fun,init);
```

Do note that, with `n=10`, you have 30 variables over which to optimize, which is a lot. This is going to be expensive and likely to get stuck in a local minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thats a problem because i have to work with at least n=200 to have enough accuracy. Do you know if there is another approach to handle that amount of variables ?

Comment: @McBotto.t: That is a general principle, not related to any one particular method: The more variables, the harder the minimization. If you can come up with a valid heuristic to solve the problem as a sequence of smaller problems, it’ll be easier. For example, maybe it’s possible to optimize for one point first, then for a second point given the first point, then for a third point given the first two, etc. Then you would be solving n problems with 3 variables, instead of a single problem with 3n variables.